# waiting for mysql query to terminate in bash script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I am trying to write a bash script that iterates through a series of mysql queries in text files. I tried using the following script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Process files

for x in {1...8}
do
    nohup mysql < coauthorquery$x.txt &
    mv nohup.out coauthor$x.csv
done
```

But it fails because nohup.out isn't present until the completion of the query in the text file. Selecting a fixed duration for a pause is not feasible because length of the query is variable. How do I pause the script until the query is complete?

Comment: Don't put it in the background, then. eliminate the `&`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [wait](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wait_%28command%29) command

```
nohup mysql < coauthorquery$x.txt &
wait
mv nohup.out coauthor$x.csv
```

Or, don't run the command in the background

```
nohup mysql < coauthorquery$x.txt
mv nohup.out coauthor$x.csv
```